# Converting multi reference propertyplaceholder into annotation for global property file location

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Current structure is XML configuration which needs to be converted to annotation configuration.

Already tried multiple ways but not getting success.

Current XML,

```
<bean id="PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="properties" ref="configurationFactoryBean" />
    </bean>
<bean id="configurationFactoryBean" class="com.config.ConfigFactoryBean">
        <constructor-arg ref="configuration" />
    </bean>
<bean id="configuration" class="org.apache.commons.configuration.CompositeConfiguration">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <!-- Centralized configuration -->
                <bean class="com.config.CentralConfiguration">
                    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="My_Service" />
                </bean>
                </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

Need to convert above configuration in ApplicationConfig.java.

Comment: How does the class definition of "ConfigFactoryBean"  looks like?

Comment: "ConfigFactoryBean" provides same functionalities as org.springmodules.commons.configuration.CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean. Basically property loader and common configuration support.

Comment: springmodules? First time to hear it . Do a little search on it and found that it last update time is 12 years ago....

Comment: That part is legacy code which I can't touch. Is it possible to convert my part to annotation?